# Stubbing with FactoryGirl, MiniTest, and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I am a big fan of FactoryGirl, but have never understood the "`.build_stubbed`" method and would like to incorporate stubbing/mocking into my TDD.  Can someone help me with the basics of what kind of stubbing I can do with FactoryGirl?  Should I start using Mocha or another similar GEM to handle the mocking/stubbing or is any of this included in the Rails 4 default MiniTest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The factory girl command `build_stubbed` means that the object is created (and also all its associated objects) but no objects are inserted into the database. You should use this if you want faster tests and do not need to have the objects in the database.

This means that the command does not have to do much with stubbing or mocking.

I myself have only experience with Mocha and can say that it very easy to use it for stubbing and mocking.

For stubbing out a command (e.g. of the object Person)

```
    person = Person.new
    person.stubs(:name).returns('Robert')
```

The obove example creates an instance of the person and stubbes out the method name to always return 'Robert'.

For mocking out the same command

```
    person = Person.new
    person.expects(:name).returns('Robert')
```

The above does the same as stubbing out the method. With the only difference that now the test fails if the method name is not called exactly once.